Encountered NaN value in between pipeline steps, sklearn's custom estimators and imblearn's custom sampler
I was trying custom estimator and custom sampler.MyFeatureConcator and MyFeatureResampler are the custom estimators that I would like to use as steps in my pipeline.
The error encountered is as:

ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
MyFeatureResampler does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values

Code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from imblearn.base import BaseSampler, SamplerMixin
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as ImbPipeline

# custom Concator
class MyFeatureConcator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, df0_cols ,concatee):
        self.concatee = concatee
        self.df0_cols = df0_cols
        
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self
        
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        x = pd.DataFrame(data= X, columns= self.df0_cols)
        X = pd.concat(objs = [x, self.concatee], axis = 1)
        return X


# custom OverSampler (SMOTE) 
class MyFeatureResampler(BaseSampler, SamplerMixin):
    def __init__(self, kneigh=None):
        self.kneigh = kneigh
        
    def fit(self, X, y= None):
        return self
        
    def _fit_resample(self, X, y=None):
        smote = SMOTE(k_neighbors= self.kneigh)
        X_resample, y_resample = smote.fit_resample(X, y)
        return (X_resample, y_resample)
        
# Estimators       
scaler = StandardScaler()
concator = MyFeatureConcator(concatee= encoded_data, df0_cols=x.columns)
logistic = LogisticRegression(max_iter=3000)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
resampler = MyFeatureResampler()

# Pipeline steps
steps = [('scaler', scaler), ('concat', concator),('rsmp', resampler), ('clf', logistic)]
pipe = ImbPipeline(steps)


# Grid params
param1 = {'clf__C': np.linspace(0,1, 5),
          'clf__penalty': ['elasticnet', 'l1', 'l2'],
          'clf__solver' : ['saga'],
          'clf__l1_ratio':np.linspace(0,1,6),
          'clf': [logistic]    
         }

param2 = {'clf__n_neighbors':np.linspace(3,20,5,dtype=np.int_),
          'clf':[knn]}

param3 = {'rsmp__kneigh': np.linspace(3,20,5, dtype=np.int_),
          'rsmp':[resampler]}

params = [param1, param2, param3]


# GridSearch
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator= pipe, param_grid=params, cv = 5, verbose=1)
grid.fit(x, target)

It is confirmed that x and target has no NaN values
This too have no NaN value shown:
pipe.named_steps['concat'].fit_transform(pipe.named_steps['scaler'].fit_transform(x)).isna().sum()

The encoded_data is the one-hot encoded for categorical data where as x is the numerical data which I wanted to scale. After scaling x I wanted to concat both x and encoded_data in one dataframe thus created a custom estimator MyFeatureConcator. The concator then returns X which is to be passed in the custom resampler MyFeatureResampler.
I'm expecting that the custom resampler receives X from the preceding concator and target from the grid.fit(X, target) which then should return the X_resampled and y_resampled which is to be passed in final step i.e a classifier.

You probably have an index mismatch problem when you concatenate; there should be another Q&A around here that addresses that, which I will try to dig up later. But also, I would generally suggest to use ColumnTransformer instead of a custom class.
